# Does AWS S3 allow specifying multiple checksum values (CRC32, CRC32C, SHA1 and SHA256) for one object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

Could there be multiple checksums added (CRC32, CRC32C, SHA1, SHA256 ) all at once, and all of these will be verified?

```
putObjectRequest.ChecksumSHA256 = "...";
putObjectRequest.ChecksumCRC32 = "...";
putObjectRequest.ChecksumCRC32C = "...";
putObjectRequest.ChecksumSHA1 = "...";
```

Here I seem can assign only 1 per request

```
request.ChecksumAlgorithm = ChecksumAlgorithm.SHA256;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use and/or check multiple additional checksum values.

You *can* use `Content-MD5` alongside **one** of these additional checksum algorithms e.g. `Content-MD5` +`x-amz-checksum-crc32` is fine but `Content-MD5` +`x-amz-checksum-crc32` + `x-amz-checksum-sha1` isn't.

It's also not a limit of 2 i.e. if you don't send the `Content-MD5` header, you can still only use one of the above additional checksums.

If you try to use more than once e.g. multiple checksums (CRC32, CRC32C, SHA1 and/or SHA256) all at once, the SDKs will throw an error that'll look like this:

> `Expecting a single x-amz-checksum- header. Multiple checksum Types are not allowed.`

The .NET SDK specifically will throw an `Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception` with error code of `InvalidRequest` with the above message.

The error message is returned by the underlying S3 API.